# Merge two dataframes in pandas with common info as columns or as cells

Tags: python, pandas, merge, pivot-table

I have two pandas dateframes in python, df_main and df_aux.

df_main is a table which gathers events, with the datetime when it happened and a column "Description" which gives a codified location. It has the following structure:

| Date | Description |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 13:45:23 | A |
| 2022-01-01 14:22:00 | C |
| 2022-01-01 16:15:33 | D |
| 2022-01-01 16:21:22 | E |
| 2022-01-02 13:21:56 | B |
| 2022-01-02 14:45:41 | B |
| 2022-01-02 15:11:34 | C |

df_aux is a table which gives the number of other events (let's say for example people walking by within Initial_Date and Final_Date) which are happening in each location (A, B, C, D), with a 1-hour granularity. The structure of df_aux is as follows:

| Initial_Date | Final_Date | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 12:00:00 | 2022-01-01 12:59:59 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| 2022-01-01 13:00:00 | 2022-01-01 13:59:59 | 3 | 2 | 4 | 5 |
| 2022-01-01 14:00:00 | 2022-01-01 14:59:59 | 2 | 2 | 7 | 0 |
| 2022-01-01 15:00:00 | 2022-01-01 15:59:59 | 5 | 2 | 2 | 0 |
| 2022-01-02 12:00:00 | 2022-01-02 12:59:59 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 3 |
| 2022-01-02 13:00:00 | 2022-01-02 13:59:59 | 5 | 5 | 0 | 3 |
| 2022-01-02 14:00:00 | 2022-01-02 14:59:59 | 2 | 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 2022-01-02 15:00:00 | 2022-01-02 15:59:59 | 3 | 4 | 1 | 0 |

So my problem is that I would need to add a new column in df_main to account for the number of people who have walked by **in the hour previous to the event**. For example, in the first event, which happens at 13:45:23h, we would go to the df_aux and look for the previous hour (12:45:23), which is the first row, as 12:45:23 is between 12:00:00 and 12:59:59. In that time range, column A has a value of 2, so we would add a new column to the df_main, "People_prev_hour", taking the value 2.

Following the same logic, the full df_main would be,

| Date | Description | People_prev_hour |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 13:45:23 | A | 2 |
| 2022-01-01 14:22:00 | C | 4 |
| 2022-01-01 16:15:33 | D | 0 |
| 2022-01-01 16:21:22 | E | NaN |
| 2022-01-02 13:21:56 | B | 1 |
| 2022-01-02 14:45:41 | B | 5 |
| 2022-01-02 15:11:34 | F | NaN |

Datetimes will always be complete between both dfs, but the Description column may not. As seen in the full df_main, two rows have as Description values E and F, which are not in df_aux. Therefore, in those cases a NaN must be present.

I can't think of a way of merging these two dfs into the desired output, as pd.merge uses common columns, and I don't manage to do anything with pd.melt or pd.pivot. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First idea was use [`merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html), because hours not overlaping intervals:

```
df1 = pd.merge_asof(df_main, 
                   df_aux.assign(Initial_Date = df_aux['Initial_Date'] + pd.Timedelta(1, 'hour')),
                   left_on='Date',
                   right_on='Initial_Date')
```

Then use [`indexing lookup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-lookup):

```
idx, cols = pd.factorize(df1['Description'])
df_main['People_prev_hour'] = (df1.reindex(cols, axis=1).to_numpy() [np.arange(len(df1)), idx])
print (df_main)
                 Date Description  People_prev_hour
0 2022-01-01 13:45:23           A               2.0
1 2022-01-01 14:22:00           C               4.0
2 2022-01-01 16:15:33           D               0.0
3 2022-01-01 16:21:22           E               NaN
4 2022-01-02 13:21:56           B               1.0
5 2022-01-02 14:45:41           B               5.0
6 2022-01-02 15:11:34           C               2.0
```

Another idea with `IntervalIndex`:

```
s = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df_aux.Initial_Date + pd.Timedelta(1, 'hour'),
                                 df_aux.Final_Date + pd.Timedelta(1, 'hour'), 'both')

df1 = df_aux.set_index(s).loc[df_main.Date]

print (df1)
                                                  Initial_Date  \
[2022-01-01 13:00:00, 2022-01-01 13:59:59] 2022-01-01 12:00:00   
[2022-01-01 14:00:00, 2022-01-01 14:59:59] 2022-01-01 13:00:00   
[2022-01-01 16:00:00, 2022-01-01 16:59:59] 2022-01-01 15:00:00   
[2022-01-01 16:00:00, 2022-01-01 16:59:59] 2022-01-01 15:00:00   
[2022-01-02 13:00:00, 2022-01-02 13:59:59] 2022-01-02 12:00:00   
[2022-01-02 14:00:00, 2022-01-02 14:59:59] 2022-01-02 13:00:00   
[2022-01-02 15:00:00, 2022-01-02 15:59:59] 2022-01-02 14:00:00   

                                                    Final_Date  A  B  C  D  
[2022-01-01 13:00:00, 2022-01-01 13:59:59] 2022-01-01 12:59:59  2  0  1  2  
[2022-01-01 14:00:00, 2022-01-01 14:59:59] 2022-01-01 13:59:59  3  2  4  5  
[2022-01-01 16:00:00, 2022-01-01 16:59:59] 2022-01-01 15:59:59  5  2  2  0  
[2022-01-01 16:00:00, 2022-01-01 16:59:59] 2022-01-01 15:59:59  5  2  2  0  
[2022-01-02 13:00:00, 2022-01-02 13:59:59] 2022-01-02 12:59:59  1  1  0  3  
[2022-01-02 14:00:00, 2022-01-02 14:59:59] 2022-01-02 13:59:59  5  5  0  3  
[2022-01-02 15:00:00, 2022-01-02 15:59:59] 2022-01-02 14:59:59  2  3  2  1
```

---

```
idx, cols = pd.factorize(df_main['Description'])
df_main['People_prev_hour'] = (df1.reindex(cols, axis=1).to_numpy() [np.arange(len(df1)), idx])
print (df_main)
                 Date Description  People_prev_hour
0 2022-01-01 13:45:23           A               2.0
1 2022-01-01 14:22:00           C               4.0
2 2022-01-01 16:15:33           D               0.0
3 2022-01-01 16:21:22           E               NaN
4 2022-01-02 13:21:56           B               1.0
5 2022-01-02 14:45:41           B               5.0
6 2022-01-02 15:11:34           C               2.0
```

Comment: Thank you very much @jezrael. Unfortunately, the first method raises a `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`.

The second method gives me a `KeyError: "None of [[Timestamp('2022-01-09 12:01:00'), Timestamp('2022-01-09 12:01:00')]] are in the [index]"` (these are dates from the real dataset, and 2022-01-09 is covered from 00:00:00 to 23:59:59h, as expected)

Comment: @datadatadata - What is `print (df_aux.dtypes)` ?

Comment: is datetime64[ns] for Initial_Date and Final_Date, and int64 for the A, B, C, D columns

Comment: @datadatadata - duplicates are expected? `print (df_aux[df_aux['Initial_Date'].duplicated(keep=False)])` ?

Comment: there are no duplicates in df_aux (but there may be duplicated dates in df_main). I run your line and outputs an Empty Dataframe, so all good. But I detected an error in my df_ux because I am using a snippet to make tests and it was not importing the date in the correct format (insted of January 9th it was interpreting September 1st). With this corrected, the second method now works, but the first is still giving the duplicates error.

Comment: @datadatadata - errors is in `merge_asof` ?

Comment: No, is in the `df_main['People_prev_hour'] = (df1.reindex(cols, axis=1).to_numpy() [np.arange(len(df1)), idx])` line

Comment: @datadatadata - Is possible in `df_aux` are duplicated columns names? `print (df_aux.loc[:, df_aux.columns.duplicated(keep=False)])`

Comment: no, also returns an empty dataframe... it's very strange indeed